Help finding 90 degree cam lock for 1960 Anderson awning window
I need help finding a cam lock that works on awning windows. The casements have 1.25 inches of trim, and the window itself has a 7/8" bezel to attach the cam lock to. The window is made of wood.
All the cam locks I see for window sashes assume the lock and cam are even with each other horizontally but I would like to find one with a keeper that can mount on the 7/8" face of the window at a 90 degree angle. Newer windows have the type of lock I need built into the frame but these old ones have no lock at all. After opening and shutting the window cold air likes to come in at the bottom, which is something I am trying to solve since the windows are double paned and I feel like replacing the entire window would be excessive.
Thank you for any assistance.


WQe usually don't allow shopping questions here, however try Rockler.com for a part. They have many things such as you are looking for.

Oh, I did not mean it to be a shopping question. I will source the part myself. I just don't know what such a thing would be called. I tried searching 90 degree window cam lock with no success.

Maybe https://kilianhardware.com/friction-sash-lock/ or https://hardwickandsons.com/products/forged-bronze-sash-lock-lift (I couldn't name it either; google image search is useful for this sort of thing.)

You might have some luck at Swisco.  How is the window currently secured?
